# Google Autocomplete Fun

Tags: code-golf, string, internet

Your task is to create a program which, given an input string, will output the first Google autocomplete result for that search. The format of input/output is up to you.

### Rules

1. Your program must take 1 input, a string, and output the top Google autocomplete/auto-fill suggestions result. The format of input/output is up to you. Just be sure to mention what your I/O format is.
2. Obviously, accessing the Internet is allowed.
3. URL shorteners (like bit.ly, TinyURL, etc.) are strictly *disallowed*. You should fetch your autocomplete results from this URL: http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=your_browser&q=your_query or http://google.com/complete/search?client=your_browser&q=your_query. You are allowed to assume any browser name (or string, for that matter) for `client`. In the [program I wrote](https://gist.github.com/ckjbgames/f7bfa353e639f4a449fc57ab0a7befd3), I assume Chrome. Any browser name or string should work. You are allowed to pass any options to the webpage as long as you are using some variant of http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search.
4. Please provide an explanation of how your program works. It is not mandatory, but I strongly advise it.
5. All standard loopholes are *strictly forbidden*.

### Test Cases

These are constantly changing, so edit this post if these become out-of-date.

```
'how to'
  => 'how to make slime'
'code golf'
  => 'code golf languages'
'you'
  => 'youtube'
'g'
  => 'google' (why would you google 'google'?)
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so may the shortest code win and the best programmer prosper...

Comment: I would standardise a client name, to make it fair

Comment: Why the strict URL? As long as suggestqueries.google.com is used, without any URL shorteners, I don't see any problems.

Comment: In particular, if we can use `output=toolbar`, we don't have to specify a client at all.

Comment: I don't think the strict url should be enforced. Banning URL shorteners should do the trick already.

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89919/quick-golf-the-gold-leader) (both involve parsing downloaded JSON objects)

Comment: Nevermind, `output=toolbar` generates XML, the OP's URL doesn't.

Comment: @Dennis I did that because it was suggested that I have a standard URL for everyone to use (by @Riker).

Comment: Well, I don't think it's a good idea. If a language can handle XML easier, why not let it use `output=toolbar` instead? There are other output methods that might also be interesting.

Comment: @Dennis Ok. I will change it where people will only have to use any URL from suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search.

Comment: @Dennis Done! Now only requires that the URL http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search be used.

Comment: @ckjbgames Why use suggestqueries? `https://www.google.com/complete` is working fine for me, too.

Comment: @mınxomaτ It gives me a 404 Error when I try, but I'm glad it works for you.

Comment: @ckjbgames Example: `https://www.google.com/complete/search?client=hp&q=a`. I'm just saying requiring that subdomain is not required.

Comment: @mınxomaτ Oh. It does work. Cool!

Comment: @mınxomaτ but why not `https -> http` (save 1 byte), remove `www.` (save 4 bytes), `google.com -> google.us` (save 1 byte) or even `google.com -> g.cn` (save 6 bytes; i'm not sure why this still works, but it seems that it still working in 20170424)

Comment: Aren't search suggestions different for different users and regions?  I don't think having standard test cases really works for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) + coreutils + w3m, <s>88</s> <s>71</s> 68 bytes

```zsh
echo `w3m "google.com/complete/search?client=gma&q=$*"|cut -d\" -f4`
```

Switching from Bash to Zsh saved 3 bytes.

*Thanks to @FatalMerlin for the shorter URL, saving 17 bytes!*

#### Sample run

```
$ zsh complete.sh how to
how to make slime
$ zsh complete.sh dont you
don't you forget about me
$ zsh complete.sh don\'t you
don't you worry child
```

Comment: Of all things, why is "make slime" the first suggestion? Just how many people are out there making slime as we speak?

Comment: No clue. It was *how to raise your i.q. by eating gifted children* for a while, so I'd consider this an improvement.

Comment: Dang, I do love w3m. It lets me browse without distractions and it's just pretty cool altogether.

Comment: @MistahFiggins Blame Minecraft for that one.

Comment: @MistahFiggins Maybe they all just want to `make(1)` [slime](https://github.com/slime/slime).

Comment: @Dennis [It's a book](https://books.google.com/books/about/How_to_Raise_Your_I_Q_by_Eating_Gifted_C.html?id=dI0QBFp9trMC)

Comment: You stand victorious.

Answer (score 12):

## Vim 8 + [unimpaired.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired), <strike>93</strike> <strike>89</strike> <strike>85</strike> <strike>70</strike> <strike>73</strike> 71 bytes

- -4 bytes thanks to tsh
- -2 bytes thanks to Ian Emnace
- -2 bytes thanks to FatalMerlin
- -1 byte thanks to tsh/ckjbgames

```
:s/ /+/g
D:e http://google.us/complete/search?client=gma&q="
d3f";D]yy
```

As a bonus, the last bytes look like they're winking at you `;D` Since this contains non-printing characters, the explanation contains substitutions (and I've replaced the pre-querystring part of the url with `[url]`, for brevity):

```
:s/ /+/g<CR>D:e [url]?client=gma&q=<C-R>"<CR>d3f";D]yy
:s/ /+/g<CR>                                           " Replace spaces with +
            D                                          " Delete and yank result
             :e                                        " Type :e ('edit' command) and a space
                [url]?client=gma&q=                    " Type the url, except the query
                                   <C-R>"              " Paste from the default register
                                         <CR>          " Execute the command, which opens the response
                                                       "   in a new buffer
                                             d3f"      " Delete through the first three quotation marks
                                                       "   This deletes everything before the suggestion
                                                 ;     " Repeat motion; this jumps to the next \"
                                                  D    " Delete everything from there, leaving only the suggestion
                                                   ]yy " unimpaired.vim C string unescape to handle escaped '
```

As far as running goes, it works fine if you save it to a file named `script` and run with `vim -s script input.txt` on macOS, at least. It doesn't work if you add `-u NONE`, but it works fine if my `.vimrc` is empty. I assume it is using something from the system `.vimrc` to make the URL stuff work. This means, however, that it doesn't work in V, so no TIO link.

Some more test cases:

```
'what' => 'whataburger'
'what ' => 'what time is it' (Seriously? People Google that?)
```

---

What I really need is a way to open a URL with spaces in it. Replacing them with `+` first is just too many bytes!

Comment: should space be replaced by plus sign`+`?

Comment: @tsh You're right! Now somebody tell me how I can save 2 bytes and beat Dennis :)

Comment: for netrw to work you need `filetype plugin on`

Comment: which is set by default in vim 8 so I guess you can say that's your language

Comment: @tbodt So why is it not set when I use `-u NONE`, I wonder?

Comment: oh it's because `-u NONE` disables plugins whereas `-u NORC` just disables vimrc

Comment: @tbodt On my machine, at least, it still fails with `-u NORC`. I checked the system vimrc and don't see any `filetype` commands. In fact, it even fails with `touch tmp.vim; vi -u tmp.vim -s script tmp.txt`.

Comment: You can paste the " register (default) in insert/command mode by doing <C-r>". You can shave off a few bytes by doing `:r [url]?client=opera&q=^R"` instead of `q:ir [url]?client=opera&q=<esc>p`. `^R` is the actual byte sent when you press <C-r>, not the keys `^` and `R` together, so it only counts as one byte.

Comment: When I [count the bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%3As%2F%20%2F%2B%2Fg%0ADq%3Air%20http%3A%2F%2Fsuggestqueries.google.com%2Fcomplete%2Fsearch%3Fclient%3Dopera%26q%3Dp%0AJd3f%22%3BD) I get 88. Also you can save bytes by changing the URL to `http://google.com/complete/search?client=hp&q=your_query` (`client=gma` => Plain JSON and shorter text.).

Comment: @FatalMerlin I think that's because the escape character was lost in translation.

Comment: @FatalMerlin But you're right about `gma`. `hp` gives me some annoying unicode-escaped html tags in the output that I can't get rid of without wasting bytes.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon ah okay, I forgot about those :) But than I'm glad that at least one thing is useful!

Comment: @IanEmnace Thank you! I forgot you could do that in command mode.

Comment: You need to save 3 bytes if you want to outgolf him again.

Comment: @ckjbgames The substitution is too verbose and I can't get rid of the protocol. Plus, I think I need to add a few bytes to handle hyphens correctly (`]yy` with the tpope/unimpaired plugin).

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Yeah. Dennis will outgolf you in the end, though.

Comment: Check out the comments on this post: You could shorten the URL to `http://g.cn/complete/search?client=gma&q=`.

Comment: @ckjbgames I get some HTML containing `301 Moved`. That said, `google.us` works.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Cool. For me, it redirects to google.cn.

Answer (score 7):

## Python + [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) <s>121</s> <s>117</s> 103 bytes

```python
from requests import*
lambda s:get("http://google.com/complete/search?client=gma&q="+s).json()[1][0][0]
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, 109 Bytes

```
q=>fetch("//suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q="+q).then(r=>r.json()).then(r=>r[1][0])
```

[`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), you gotta love it, but man is it verbose! This answer uses [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), a promise-based fetch API present in modern browsers. Promises work by establishing handlers for async actions at the beginning, like callbacks, but better. The `.then()` takes a function which will be called with the result of the async action. `.then(r=>r.json())` uses the [`.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) response method to convert the text array to a manipulable variable, the second `.then()` just pulls the first response.

Usage:

```
S = q=>fetch("//suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q="+q).then(r=>r.json()).then(r=>r[1][0])

S("node.js").then(console.log); // Prints the result to the debug console
```

Comment: `.then(r=>r.json()).then(r=>r[1][0])` -> `.then(r=>r.json()[1][0])` Enjoy 11 characters less ;-)

Comment: I've tried in Firefox 52 and Chrome 57, on this page, Google's homepage, and about:blank, and I just keep getting CORS errors. Have you gotten it to work successfully?

Comment: @ETHproductions Yes, there are CORS problems, you must execute on the domain https://suggestqueries.google.com

Comment: @StephanBijzitter [`.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) returns a Promise, it's async, for some reason

Comment: Indeed it works there, thanks!

Comment: Oh, you're completely right! I never even noticed ;O

Comment: Promise's verbosity isn't the problem, it's `fetch`. I'd really love to know why `.json()` is async.

Comment: [OIC](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/240). Because `fetch()` returns before the body has necessarily even been fully received.

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, <strike>133</strike> 115 bytes

```
([net.webclient]::new().downloadstring("http://google.com/complete/search?client=gma&q=$_")|convertfrom-json)[1][0]
```

**Sample run**

**Windows CMD command line:**

```
powershell.exe -c "'code golf l'|%{([net.webclient]::new().downloadstring(""""http://google.com/complete/search?client=gma&q=$_"""")|convertfrom-json)[1][0]}"
```

**PowerShell console:**

```
'code golf l'|%{([net.webclient]::new().downloadstring("http://google.com/complete/search?client=gma&q=$_")|convertfrom-json)[1][0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, <strike>192</strike> <strike>112</strike> 111 Bytes

Saved 80 Bytes thanks to @TheLethalCoder. Thanks for reformatting my code, I didn't know it was allowed to just leave off the surrounding Class and Method Body :)

Saved another Byte by replacing `gma` by `hp`, as it doesn't matter for the parsing and there is just some gibberish before the response body.

I litterally brute-forced the API to find `gma` and `hp`.

```
s=>new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://google.com/complete/search?client=hp&q="+s).Split('"')[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 122 bytes

```
{Eval.me(new URL("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q="+it).text.split(",\\{")[0]+"]")[1][0]}
```

Basically:

1. Get the text from the end-point.
2. Remove the part with the brackets at the end, this isn't valid syntax.
3. Parse the remaining bit as a groovy array.
4. Grab the second element of the result array.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### R, 111 bytes

Long time since I last came here but giving it a shot:

```
jsonlite::fromJSON(readLines(url(paste0("http://google.com/complete/search?client=gma&q=",scan(,"")))))[[2]][1]
```

Using the package `jsonlite` to convert the string fetched from `readLines()` into a list object.

Subsequently extract the second element, e.g (gives a warning that we don't have to care about):

```
> jsonlite::fromJSON(readLines(url(paste0("http://google.com/complete/search?client=gma&q=",scan(,"")))))[[2]][1]
1: "how to"
2: 
    Read 1 item
[[1]]
[1] "how to make slime"

Warning message:
    In readLines(url(paste0("http://google.com/complete/search?client=gma&q=",  :
                                incomplete final line found on 'http://google.com/complete/search?client=gma&q=how to'
```

Answer (score 0):

### C#, 127 bytes

```
s=>new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=gma&q="+s).Split('"')[3];
```

Complete and formatted version:

```
static void Main()
{
    System.Func<string, string> f = s =>
        new System.Net.WebClient()
                      .DownloadString("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=gma&q="+s)
                      .Split('"')[3];

    System.Console.WriteLine(f("you"));
    System.Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint about leaving of the Method and Class Body!